# Git submodule: link submodule to local development checkout

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a public Github project (library project) that I use as a library in multiple other projects of mine (project A and project B). I pulled in the library project repository as a submodule into the (private) repositories of project A and project B. While I am working on those other projects I might find the need to change or expand the library project.

How do I make it easy for me to make changes to a local checkout of the library project that get reflected immediately in my checkouts of project A and project B while working on them?

I tried replacing the library project submodule folder with a symbolic link to the local checkout of the library project repository (kinda like what `npm link` in the JS/NPM ecosystem does), but git, instead of following the symlink recognizes this as a `typechange` to the submodule folder. Which seems consistent with how Git handles symlinks, but not really useful in this case.

It seems hard links (for individual files) and bind mounts (requiring root privileges) are often suggested to similar questions on stackoverflow, but not really the solution here either.

Are there any other suggestions or recommendations for how to enable this workflow?

Comment: Just edit the submodule code inside A and B directly and push/pull to synchronize between them and GitHub?

Comment: I thought about this for a while. I wasn't sure why this hadn't occurred to me. I think there are two reasons, neither of them great after having thought about them some more. (See follow up comments)

Comment: 1) I was trying to avoid having to push changes to Github before being able to test them and work with them in both project A and project B locally. I was thinking too much in centralized terms, forgetting that I could just pull changes from projectA/library to projectB/library directly without having to push them through Github prior to being ready for public release.

Comment: 2) When adding the submodule to the project I will have to add it using the authenticated URL to be able to push to Github. This might conflict with Project A and B collaborators that do not have authenticated access to the library project. However, I did not consider that I could just continue using the submodule via the unauthenticated HTTPS URL and add an additional authenticated origin locally for pushing to Github.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Please consider turning your comment into an answer so I can accept it. Appreciate it, thank you!